# Using rpcgen with C++

Tags: c++, c, unix

I'm using the rpcgen libraries to create an application where I have to use a hashmap on the server side. Is it advisable to use the STL libraries (or any C++ code) with rpcgen? I've tried compiling the files with g++ and it works. Or would I be better off implementing something like a linked list instead of a hashmap (I'm assuming complexity is not an issue) while sticking with C?

Something like this : My input file is

```
struct intpair {
        int a;
        int b;
};

program ADD_PROG {
        version ADD_VERS {
                int ADD(intpair) = 1;
        } = 1;
} = 0x23451111;
```

(from http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/rutgers/notes/rpc/index.html).

I want to use a hashmap on the server side. I tried doing something like this in my server side file:

```
#include "add.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

int *
add_1_svc(intpair *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> voteList;

    static int result;
    std::string s = "Aa";

    voteList.insert(std::pair<std::string, int> ("ABC", 100));
    printf("Add called\n");

    return &result;
}
```

and it works. I did have to rename the files and use g++ though.

Comment: Can you show us an example small input file for rpcgen that shows what you mean?

Comment: Added an example. I need to implement a data structure to represent a database, but I'm not sure if using the stl hashmap is good practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the C++ STL components don't "leak" through the interface you're implementing, so it should be all fine and good.  One thing to be aware of is exception safety: you might want to add a top-level try/catch block to convert any exceptions into an appropriate error.

Comment: Can you explain about how the components might leak? This is the first time I'm trying this, so I don't know much about the potential pitfalls.

Comment: What I mean is you aren't trying to send or receive C++ classes via the RPC interface--you're just using C++ classes inside the implementation.  The former would probably be a mistake; the latter should work if you're careful about exceptions.